# How to synchronize two stepper motor.. using DRV8825

Tags: python, gpio

I'm currently using this code, and open for a new codes.I can't synchronize the two motor. And how can i call the two stepper motor. and i want to know how to vary the speed of two motors. what is the proper looping in this code to make the stepper synchronize.

```
from  time import  sleep
import  RPi.GPIO as GPIO

DIR  =  20
STEP  =  21
CW  =  1          #THIS IS FOR STEPPER 1
CCW  =  0
SPR  =  2000

DIR1  = 23
STEP1  =  24
CW  = 1            # THIS IS FOR STEPPER 2
CCW  =  0
SPR  =  2000

stepcount =  SPR
delay1 =  0.001
delay =  0.001

for  x  in range(stepcount):
    GPIO.output(STEP, GPIO.HIGH)      #Code for Stepper 1 Clockwise
    sleep(delay)
    GPIO.output(STEP, GPIO.LOW)
    sleep(delay)
sleep(0.5)
GPIO.ouput(DIR, CW)

for  x  in range(stepcount):
    GPIO.output(STEP, GPIO.HIGH)
    sleep(delay)
    GPIO.output(STEP, GPIO.LOW)       #Code for stepper 1 Counter clockwise
    sleep(delay)
sleep(0.5)
GPIO.ouput(DIR, CCW)

for  x  in range(stepcount):
    GPIO.output(STEP1, GPIO.HIGH)
    sleep(delay)
    GPIO.output(STEP1, GPIO.LOW)         # Code for stepper 2
    sleep(delay1)
sleep(0.5)
GPIO.ouput(DIR1, CW1)
```